# Xpages to call Rest service with auth Token

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib, ssjs

I need to call some APIs in a Oracle app called Taleo. I have the documentation and was able to get a my calls to work in a REST plugin in Firefox and in a REST Mac Client app,"Paw".

I first have to send credentials to get a auth Token cookie:

https://chj.tbe.taleo.net/chj06/ats/api/v1/login?orgCode=XXXXXXS&userName=XXXXX&password=XXXXXX

If I call this then I receive the authToken  [webapi2=numbers].

Then I can use essentially the same URL to POST,GET,PUT,DELETE etc. to different objects, for example a GET to

https://chj.tbe.taleo.net/chj06/ats/api/v1/object/location

with JSON in the body for creating a location.

I think I would like to write a java agent (so it can be schedule) to, for example, to interrogate the data on my system and then create, update, delete as appropriate on the remote system.

I am much more comfortable using LotusScript/SSJS and the built in Rest controls, but probably should take the plunge and do this in Java, but where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with an **Java** agent as you want to run your code in background.

Use Java's native HTTP classes

- `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and
- `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

for HTTP connection. You can find an easy example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) as a starting point.

Alternatively you could use more comfortable APIs like [Apache's HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html).

If you want/have to stay with **LotusScript** then you could create a Java class which realizes all HTTP connections and instantiate the class in LotusScript agent per LS2J.
If you have a Windows Domino server then you could use [WinHttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) with CreateObject() and stay with pure LotusScript.